# Kafka Streaming application will automatically create consumers in group based on the number of partitions available in a Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

Well i am new to kafka just wanted to know whether
Kafka Streaming application will automatically create consumers in group based on the number of partitions available in a Kafka topic?

Answer (score 0):

The number of the consumers in Kafka Streams application is based on `num.stream.threads` property, by default it equals to 1